# Binary Search Tree Traversals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees

Draw a BST when you insert, $O,V,E,R,F,L,C,W$ from left-to-right and determine the order of the nodes when using post-order traversal and pre-order traversal.

My attempt at drawing the BST:

```
             O
           /   \
          E     V
         /  \  / \
        C    F R  W
              \   
               L
```

post-order traversal I got $C,L,F,E,R,W,V,O$ and for pre-order traversal I got $O,E,C,F,L,V,R,W$

However I'm not 100% sure if what I got both for the drawing of the BST and the traversal's are correct. I was wondering if anyone can check to see if I did this correctly(if my solutions match what you got). I feel that I might of drawn my tree wrong therefore I think that my traversal might be wrong as well.

Comment: Seems correct to me $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. The binary tree representation should be straightforward. For the preorder and postorder traversals, I recommend you think about the following pieces of pseudocode:

> preorder(node)
>
> if node == null then return
>
> > visit(node)
> >
> > preorder(node.left)
> >
> > preorder(node.right)
>
> postorder(node)
>
> > if node == null then return
> >
> > postorder(node.left)
> >
> > postorder(node.right)
> >
> > visit(node)

The preorder should be fairly straightforward. The postorder is trickier to think about, but only slightly.